# jSon file converted to html table in JS (jQuery), Tablesorter doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: jquery, json, tablesorter

I've tried many things, searched docs, forums and such without success. I'm writing a cloud file server table of reports (can't run php). Web page table is sourced from a json file (lint = good). It contains column data from a database. Each directory containing reports is named identical to each unique id (an integer) in the database. So, the first column contains a hyperlink who's src and text is an integer string. The result is a page with the header displaying header icons (proper) but doesn't sort. It also displays one filter box under the first column header but is missing in the other 8. What am I doing wrong with this?

```
// edit- json file is an array of objects ([{"JOBID":"1234567","PROD":"Widget", ...

var thisWeb = "/reports/thisWeb.json";
$.getJSON(thisWeb, function(data) {
    var tbl_head = "";
    $.each(data[0], function(key, value) {
        tbl_head += "<th data-sorter='text'>" + key + "</th>";
        console.log(value);
    });
    $('table thead').html(tbl_head);

    console.log(tbl_head);

    var tbl_body = "";
    $.each(data, function() {
        var tbl_row = "";
        var hlink = "<a href='/reports/" + this.PROD + "/" + this.JOBID + "'>";
        $.each(this, function(key, value) {
            if (key == "JOBID") {tbl_row += "<td>" + hlink + value + "</a></td>";}
            else {tbl_row += "<td>" + value + "</td>";}
        });
        tbl_body += "<tr>" + tbl_row + "</tr>";
    });
    $('table tbody').html(tbl_body);
})
.done(function() {
        // call the tablesorter plugin 
        console.log("tablesorter");
        $("table").tablesorter({ 
            debug: true,
            // initialize zebra striping and filter widgets 
            theme: 'blue',
            widgets: ["zebra", "filter"], 
            widgetOptions : { 
                // external filter (column specific or any match)
                filter_external : '.search',
                // add a default type search to the first name column
                filter_defaultFilter: { 1 : '~{query}' },
                // include column filters
                filter_columnFilters: true,
                filter_placeholder: { search : 'Search...' },
                filter_saveFilters : true,
                filter_reset: '.reset',

            } 
        });
      console.log("filters applied");
})
.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      tbl_body = "<tr><td>" + thisWeb + " not found</td></tr>";
      $("table").html(tbl_body);
      console.log('Report list not found ' + textStatus);
});

<main>
<!--      <div id='main'>-->
    <input data-lastsearchtime="1425684650894" class="search" data-column="all" type="search">
    <button type="button" class="reset">Reset Search</button>

<!--    <script> console.log("setting up table"); </script>-->
    <table role="grid" id="objTable" class="tablesorter tablesorter-blue hasFilters" cellspacing="1">
        <thead role="row" class="tablesorter-headerRow"><th aria-label="JOBID: No sort applied, activate to apply an ascending sort" aria-sort="none" style="-moz-user-select: none;" unselectable="on" aria-controls="objTable" aria-disabled="false" role="columnheader" scope="col" tabindex="0" class="tablesorter-header tablesorter-headerUnSorted" data-sorter="text"><div class="tablesorter-header-inner">JOBID</div></th><th aria-label="PROD: No sort applied, activate to apply an ascending sort" aria-sort="none" style="-moz-user-select: none;" unselectable="on" aria-controls="objTable" aria-disabled="false" role="columnheader" scope="col" tabindex="0" class="tablesorter-header tablesorter-headerUnSorted" data-sorter="text"><div class="tablesorter-header-inner">PROD</div></th><th aria-label="JOB_TITLE: No sort applied, activate to apply an ascending sort" aria-sort="none" style="-moz-user-select: none;" unselectable="on" aria-controls="objTable" aria-disabled="false" role="columnheader" scope="col" tabindex="0" class="tablesorter-header tablesorter-headerUnSorted" data-sorter="text"><div class="tablesorter-header-inner">JOB_TITLE</div></th><th aria-label="SOURCE: No sort applied, activate to apply an ascending sort" aria-sort="none" style="-moz-user-select: none;" unselectable="on" aria-controls="objTable" aria-disabled="false" role="columnheader" scope="col" tabindex="0" class="tablesorter-header tablesorter-headerUnSorted" data-sorter="text"><div class="tablesorter-header-inner">SOURCE</div></th><th aria-label="CHARGE: No sort applied, activate to apply an ascending sort" aria-sort="none" style="-moz-user-select: none;" unselectable="on" aria-controls="objTable" aria-disabled="false" role="columnheader" scope="col" tabindex="0" class="tablesorter-header tablesorter-headerUnSorted" data-sorter="text"><div class="tablesorter-header-inner">CHARGE</div></th><th aria-label="PRODNAME: No sort applied, activate to apply an ascending sort" aria-sort="none" style="-moz-user-select: none;" unselectable="on" aria-controls="objTable" aria-disabled="false" role="columnheader" scope="col" tabindex="0" class="tablesorter-header tablesorter-headerUnSorted" data-sorter="text"><div class="tablesorter-header-inner">PRODNAME</div></th><th aria-label="TECH: No sort applied, activate to apply an ascending sort" aria-sort="none" style="-moz-user-select: none;" unselectable="on" aria-controls="objTable" aria-disabled="false" role="columnheader" scope="col" tabindex="0" class="tablesorter-header tablesorter-headerUnSorted" data-sorter="text"><div class="tablesorter-header-inner">TECH</div></th><th aria-label="LOTID: No sort applied, activate to apply an ascending sort" aria-sort="none" style="-moz-user-select: none;" unselectable="on" aria-controls="objTable" aria-disabled="false" role="columnheader" scope="col" tabindex="0" class="tablesorter-header tablesorter-headerUnSorted" data-sorter="text"><div class="tablesorter-header-inner">LOTID</div></th><th aria-label="WAFER: No sort applied, activate to apply an ascending sort" aria-sort="none" style="-moz-user-select: none;" unselectable="on" aria-controls="objTable" aria-disabled="false" role="columnheader" scope="col" tabindex="0" class="tablesorter-header tablesorter-headerUnSorted" data-sorter="text"><div class="tablesorter-header-inner">WAFER</div></th><tr role="row" class="tablesorter-filter-row"><td><input data-lastsearchtime="1425684650887" data-column="0" class="tablesorter-filter" placeholder="Search..." type="search"></td></tr></thead>
        <tbody aria-relevant="all" aria-live="polite">
          <tr style="display: table-row;" class="odd" role="row"><td><a href="/reports/widgets/2014544">2014544</a></td><td>widgets</td><td>Return BHD098</td><td>Return</td><td>Acc 12 (DD1.0)</td><td>Widgets Base (Eng)</td><td>RW -Raw</td><td>1124RWSO084.000</td><td>6M03L066SOD1</td></tr>
          <tr style="display: table-row;" class="even" role="row"><td><a href="/reports/widgets/2016457">2016457</a></td><td>widgets</td><td>Test SN100111</td><td>Quality</td><td>Acc 1</td><td>Widegets 2.0 (Eng)</td><td>RW -Raw</td><td>12323SZP002.000</td><td>6L02J184SOG1</td></tr>
       </tbody>
    </table>
</main>
```

Comment: Can you share what the resulting HTML looks like... if you need to modify the code for confidentiality, then please just share one or two rows (with & without a JOBID) from the tbody.

Answer (score 0):

Mottie asked me for output html which started my answer - Header is a row and TH needs to be wrapped in TR. Simple answer. It now filters and sorts properly (and quickly).

```
var tbl_head = "<tr>"; // <tr> added
$.each(data[0], function(key, value) {
    tbl_head += "<th data-sorter='text'>" + key + "</th>";
});
tbl_head += "</tr>";   // this line added
$('table thead').html(tbl_head);
```